# How to get newly updated resources from a REST API?

Tags: mysql, sql, api, rest

In a typical REST API you can get all books as follows:

```
GET /books
```

However, I then want to be able to poll the server (e.g. every 10sec) to fetch any books that was updated, without re-fetching all the books I have already fetched. My first thought was to do it using an updated-at time stamp.

For example, if in the last request the newest book was updated at `2020-06-01 10:30:25.125`, I can do a request as follows to get all the books that was updated after that timestamp.

```
GET /books?updated_at_gt=2020-06-01-10-30-25-125
```

This would work most of the time. However, there are a few corner cases.

## The problem

The issue with this approach is that the `updated_at` timestamps is precise to the closest millisecond. This would cause a problem if multiple records are updated at the same millisecond. This may sound rare but it could happen on batch edits.

For example, consider the following sequence of events:

- Book 1 is updated at 20.000000s. Therefore `updated_at` is stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.000`
- Book 2 is updated at 25.125000s. Therefore `updated_at` is stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.125`
- At 25.125250s `GET /books` will get book 1 and 2, as expected.
- Book 3 is updated at `25.125455s`. Therefore `updated_at` is also stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.125` (same as book 2)
- `GET /books?updated_at_gt=2020-06-01-10-30-25-125` will miss book 3.

## Workaround

My work-around is when an API call is done the first time at `2020-06-01 10:30:00.200`, it will actually fetch all the books that was updated 50ms earlier that the server request time.

For example, consider the same scenario:

- Book 1 is updated at 20.000000s. Therefore `updated_at` is stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.000`
- Book 2 is updated at 25.125000s. Therefore `updated_at` is stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.125`
- At 25.125250s `GET /books` will get all books updated before 24.625250s‬. So it will get book 1, but not 2.
- Book 3 is updated at `25.125455s`. Therefore `updated_at` is also stored as: `2020-06-01 10:30:25.125` (same as book 2)
- `GET /books?updated_at_gt=2020-06-01-10-30-25-000` will get book 2 and book 3.

This seems like a complicated work-around.

Is there a better way?

Comment: it's a type of race condition then? If your request comes in while a book is being updated, you'll never be able to get that book based on time? By the time the response reaches you the updated book's time is in the past.

Comment: I know. so what would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot add a comment yet due to reputation.

To be honest I am not exactly following why its missed, regardless of the extra millisecond details, if you aren't storing them, how is it going to miss it if what you store at the update_at_gt is exactly the same?

that being said, why not setup a between situation. Store the updated times, but keep track of the last time you called and do a between your old time and new time

So you would make sure that your first query would always be something that was way before you would care so

updated_at_gt > 2020-01-01-00-00-00-000 and updated_at_gt <= the current time (up to whatever is the max milliseconds etc) you are gonna store.

Then you would store the time that was <= too, so that next time, it will be the updated_at_gt > time. This way it will never return a book it did when it was <=.

So

Query one
updated_at_gt > 2020-01-01-00-00-00-000 and updated_at_gt <= 2020-06-01 10:35:01.1245665

Query two

updated_at_gt > 2020-06-01 10:35:01.1245665 and <= 2020-06-01 10:35:11.1245665

just as an example.

Comment: I am storing the `updated_at` information, but it only stores to the nearest millisecond. So I can't do: `2020-06-01 10:35:01.1245665`, but I can store: `2020-06-01 10:35:01.125`. This is how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Epoch time to pass in the API. Epoch time for 2020-06-11 5:31:53 AM GMT is 1591853513. The epoch time can be generated to millisecond accuracy so once the server receives the epoch time it can subtract the millisecond directly and return the books needed based on it. Refer - https://www.epochconverter.com for epoch converter. Using epoch time would be a cleaner solution instead of passing date time value in the query parameter.

```
GET /books?updated_at_gt=1591853513
```

Another solutions - If modifications are possible on the code base and database I suggest you add a flag which is updated for all the books send in the GET API call. In that way you would not have to check against any time but only the flag.